# Usage of the prepositional phrase ''at the campfire''

Tags: word-order, prepositional-phrases

> I could hear the man **at the campfire** singing.

What does '' at the campfire'' work here?
I want to know whether it modifies **'the man'** or **'hear'** in this sentence?

Comment: In _I could hear the man at the campfire singing,_ "at the campfire" modifies "the man." In order to modify the verb, the sentence would have to be the somewhat ambiguous _At the campfire I hear the man singing,_ or the torturous _I hear at the campfire the man singing._ The phrase could modify "singing" if placed at the end: _I hear the man singing at the campfire._

Comment: We found Behrman in his room helpless .What does ''in his room ''  modify.?

Comment: Behrman  .  .  .  .  .  .  .probably.

Comment: Why?Explain it to me more.

Comment: First: where is the participle in the "participle phrase" _at the campfire?_

Comment: Thanks for correcting my careless mistake.I have edited it

Comment: I suggest a separate question about Behrman.

Answer (score 1):

> I could hear the man **at the campfire** singing.

Here the prepositional phrase **'at the campfire'** is referring to the subject **'the man'**.

It means that: *There was a man who was sitting near a campfire and he was singing and I could hear him.*